# Is it possible to make objects (annotated) visible and the background (unannotated) black or white using roboflow?

Tags: mask, image-segmentation, roboflow

Dear Altruist!
I have a dataset that contains original images and corresponding annotation (JSON) which was annotated with labelme, I want to convert the image in such a format (attached image) that only the annotated instance will be visible and the background will be erased or in a single color (black/white.

How can I do that in Roboflow?
Is there any other site that can help me do that?

[The image should be look like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik1CJ.png)